# Unable to print feature layer from my ArcGIS Server

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

*EDIT :*

*I replaced the url to my arcgis server by the IP address and everything worked. It was probably a problem with the web adaptor.*

I am trying to print a map that I made with ArcGIS Server 10.2 and ArcGIS javascript API. If I remove the layers from ArcGIS Server it works (with ESRI basemap)

The problem is that I keep getting an error (code: 400, message: "Unable to complete operation.", details: Array[1], log: undefined, httpCode: 400).

which is more specifically -->

```
Unable to complete operation.
Error executing tool.: Layer "graphicsLayer8": Failed to create layer from service at http://MYSERVER.com/arcgis/rest/services/Tests/MyFirstMapService/MapServer/2. Layer "graphicsLayer9": Failed to create layer from service at http://MYSERVER.com/arcgis/rest/services/Tests/MyFirstMapService/MapServer/2. Layer "graphicsLayer10": Failed to create layer from service at http://MYSERVER.com/arcgis/rest/services/Tests/MyFirstMapService/MapServer/0. Failed to execute (Export Web Map). Failed to execute (Export Web Map Task).
```

I get the error if I try to do it via my web server or directly off the ArcGIS Server by doing :

```
    http://MYSERVER.com/arcgis/rest/services/Utilities/PrintingTools/GPServer/Export%20Web%20Map%20Task/execute?Web_Map_as_JSON=%7B%22mapOptions%22%3A%7B%22showAttribution%22%3Atrue%2C%22extent%22%3A%7B%22xmin%22%3A-9023064.378303602%2C%22ymin%22%3A5567074.228631147%2C%22xmax%22%3A-6082990.5223433655%2C%22ymax%22%3A7675513.216848888%2C%22spatialReference%22%3A%7B%22wkid%22%3A102100%7D%7D%2C%22spatialReference%22%3A%7B%22wkid%22%3A102100%7D%2C%22scale%22%3A9244648.868617998%7D%2C%22operationalLayers%22%3A%5B%7B%22id%22%3A%22layer0%22%2C%22title%22%3A%22layer0%22%2C%22opacity%22%3A1%2C%22minScale%22%3A591657527.591555%2C%22maxScale%22%3A1128.497176%2C%22url%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fservices.arcgisonline.com%2FArcGIS%2Frest%2Fservices%2FWorld_Street_Map%2FMapServer%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%22graphicsLayer8%22%2C%22title%22%3A%22graphicsLayer8%22%2C%22opacity%22%3A1%2C%22minScale%22%3A0%2C%22maxScale%22%3A0%2C%22layerDefinition%22%3A%7B%22drawingInfo%22%3A%7B%22renderer%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22simple%22%2C%22symbol%22%3A%7B%22color%22%3Anull%2C%22outline%22%3A%7B%22color%22%3A%5B46%2C46%2C46%2C255%5D%2C%22width%22%3A3%2C%22type%22%3A%22esriSLS%22%2C%22style%22%3A%22esriSLSSolid%22%7D%2C%22type%22%3A%22esriSFS%22%2C%22style%22%3A%22esriSFSSolid%22%7D%7D%7D%7D%2C%22url%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2FMYSERVER.com%2Farcgis%2Frest%2Fservices%2FTests%2FMyFirstMapService%2FMapServer%2F2%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%22graphicsLayer9%22%2C%22title%22%3A%22graphicsLayer9%22%2C%22opacity%22%3A0%2C%22minScale%22%3A0%2C%22maxScale%22%3A0%2C%22layerDefinition%22%3A%7B%22drawingInfo%22%3A%7B%22renderer%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22simple%22%2C%22symbol%22%3A%7B%22color%22%3A%5B46%2C46%2C46%2C255%5D%2C%22outline%22%3A%7B%22color%22%3A%5B46%2C46%2C46%2C255%5D%2C%22width%22%3A3%2C%22type%22%3A%22esriSLS%22%2C%22style%22%3A%22esriSLSSolid%22%7D%2C%22type%22%3A%22esriSFS%22%2C%22style%22%3A%22esriSFSSolid%22%7D%7D%7D%7D%2C%22url%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2FMYSERVER.com%2Farcgis%2Frest%2Fservices%2FTests%2FMyFirstMapService%2FMapServer%2F2%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%22graphicsLayer10%22%2C%22title%22%3A%22graphicsLayer10%22%2C%22opacity%22%3A1%2C%22minScale%22%3A0%2C%22maxScale%22%3A0%2C%22layerDefinition%22%3A%7B%22drawingInfo%22%3A%7B%22renderer%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22simple%22%2C%22label%22%3A%22%22%2C%22description%22%3A%22%22%2C%22symbol%22%3A%7B%22color%22%3A%5B204%2C64%2C57%2C255%5D%2C%22size%22%3A8%2C%22angle%22%3A0%2C%22xoffset%22%3A0%2C%22yoffset%22%3A0%2C%22type%22%3A%22esriSMS%22%2C%22style%22%3A%22esriSMSSquare%22%2C%22outline%22%3A%7B%22color%22%3A%5B120%2C64%2C61%2C255%5D%2C%22width%22%3A0.25%2C%22type%22%3A%22esriSLS%22%2C%22style%22%3A%22esriSLSSolid%22%7D%7D%7D%7D%7D%2C%22url%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2FMYSERVER.COM%2Farcgis%2Frest%2Fservices%2FTests%2FMyFirstMapService%2FMapServer%2F0%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%22map_graphics%22%2C%22opacity%22%3A1%2C%22minScale%22%3A0%2C%22maxScale%22%3A0%2C%22featureCollection%22%3A%7B%22layers%22%3A%5B%5D%7D%7D%5D%2C%22exportOptions%22%3A%7B%22outputSize%22%3A%5B800%2C1100%5D%2C%22dpi%22%3A96%7D%2C%22layoutOptions%22%3A%7B%22titleText%22%3A%22Un+titre%22%2C%22authorText%22%3A%22MSSS%2C+Direction+de+la+gestion+int%C3%A9gr%C3%A9e+de+l%27information.%22%2C%22copyrightText%22%3A%22%3Ccopyright+info+here%3E%22%2C%22scaleBarOptions%22%3A%7B%22metricUnit%22%3A%22esriKilometers%22%2C%22metricLabel%22%3A%22km%22%2C%22nonMetricUnit%22%3A%22esriMiles%22%2C%22nonMetricLabel%22%3A%22mi%22%7D%2C%22legendOptions%22%3A%7B%22operationalLayers%22%3A%5B%5D%7D%7D%7D&Format=PDF&Layout_Template=A3+Landscape&env%3AoutSR=&env%3AprocessSR=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&f=html
```

I guess that means it's not a proxy or CORS problem.

Here's the code for the printing part :

```
printUrl = "http://MySERVER.com/arcgis/rest/services/Utilities/PrintingTools/GPServer/Export%20Web%20Map%20Task";

    var printInfo = esriRequest({
      "url": printUrl,
      "content": { "f": "json" }
    });
    printInfo.then(dojo.hitch(printUrl,dojo.hitch(myMap,handlePrintInfo)), handleError);

    function handlePrintInfo(resp) {


      var layoutTemplate, templateNames, mapOnlyIndex, templates;

      layoutTemplate = arrayUtils.filter(resp.parameters, function(param, idx) {
        return param.name === "Layout_Template";
      });

      if ( layoutTemplate.length === 0 ) {
        console.log("print service parameters name for templates must be \"Layout_Template\"");
        return;
      }
      templateNames = layoutTemplate[0].choiceList;

      // remove the MAP_ONLY template then add it to the end of the list of templates 
      mapOnlyIndex = arrayUtils.indexOf(templateNames, "MAP_ONLY");
      if ( mapOnlyIndex > -1 ) {
        var mapOnly = templateNames.splice(mapOnlyIndex, mapOnlyIndex + 1)[0];
        templateNames.push(mapOnly);
      }

      // create a print template for each choice
      templates = arrayUtils.map(templateNames, function(ch) {
        var plate = new PrintTemplate();
        plate.layout = plate.label = ch;
        plate.format = "PDF";
        plate.layoutOptions = { 
          "authorText": "Author.",
          "copyrightText": "<copyright info here>",
          "legendLayers": [], 
          "titleText": "A title", 
          "scalebarUnit": "Kilometers" 
        };
        return plate;
      });

      // create the print dijit
      var printer = new Print({
        "map": myMap,
        "templates": templates,
        "url": printUrl
      }, dojo.byId("print_button"));
      printer.startup();
    }

    function handleError(err) {
      console.log("Something broke: ", err);
    }`
```

Comment: Are those feature services secured, or require a user name and password to access them through ArcGIS Server? Feature Services behind token security would require tokens to be added to the print task call.

Comment: These feature services are NOT secured

Comment: are you referring to the print server the same way you refer to your graphicsLayers within your webmap JSON? (ie: do both of the urls contain 'tcn00qubc01341:6080'

Comment: @John Gravois - Yes.

Comment: tough to say, there's a ton going on in your webmap json.  i'd recommend adding in layers on at a time to see if one in particular is the problem.

Comment: I tried that already, as soon as one of those layers is added the error happens. Could you please edit your comment to hide the url to my server please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed the URL call to my arcgis server to the ip address and the map finally prints. Probably a problem with the web adaptor.

Comment: Do we know the issue with the web adapter that cause this? We are experiencing the same issue.